# Changing color for Modified Files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I want to change the colors of text for my theme. I want to change the color that VS Code makes edited files. I have tried

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]": {
        "editorOverviewRuler.modifiedForeground": "#ff0000",
        "editorOverviewRuler.warningForeground": "#ff0000"
    }
}
```

per the documentation, but that doesn't do anything, and I can't find any other parameters that woulda affect the color specific to files that have been edited and not yet saved or committed to GIT. I do know it can be changed, because that color is different between Monokai and Monokai Alt.

Can anyone help? The color manipulation of this IDE is beyond frustrating.

[image: modified content]

Comment: `gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground` ?

Comment: SOLVED! Thank you

Comment: if it's solved, where is the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex game me the answer ...

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]": {
        "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground" : "#ff0000"
    }
}
```

#ff0000 being the color edited files are now marked as in the browser tab

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.